# Loop through a collection and return a new collection where objects with the same id are combined

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have this javascript array.

```
var events = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane','Bella']},
  {id: 3, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 4, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Ted', 'Laura']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Jim', 'Samantha']},
];
```

What I need is to reduce this array to look like this:

```
var events = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane','Bella']},
  {id: 3, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 4, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane', 'Ted', 'Laura', 'Jim', 'Samantha']}
];
```

Where the array has been reduced that there is only one object with each id and the invitees array within each object shows all invitees.

I'm having trouble just getting started with the basic logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce()` and `forEach()` like this.

```js
var events = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane','Bella']},
  {id: 3, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 4, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Ted', 'Gary', 'Laura']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Jim', 'Samantha']}
];

var o = {}
var result = events.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!o[e.id]) {
    o[e.id] = e;
    r.push(o[e.id]);
  } else {
    e.invitees.forEach(function(a) {
      if (o[e.id].invitees.indexOf(a) == -1) o[e.id].invitees.push(a);
    })
  }
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

You could also use `Set` instead of `forEach()` loop to remove duplicates.

```js
var events = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane','Bella']},
  {id: 3, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 4, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Ted', 'Gary', 'Laura']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Jim', 'Samantha']}
];

var o = {}
var result = events.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!o[e.id]) {
    o[e.id] = e;
    r.push(o[e.id]);
  } else {
    o[e.id].invitees = [...new Set(o[e.id].invitees.concat(e.invitees))];
  }
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `Set` is nice, also consider `Map` instead of a pojo. And a `for of` loop instead of `reduce` which makes little sense here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this ES6 *functional programming* style code:

```
var result = Array.from (
    events.reduce ( (acc, obj) => acc.set(obj.id,
        Object.assign({}, obj, {invitees: [...new Set(
            [...(acc.get(obj.id) || obj).invitees, ...obj.invitees] )]})
    ), new Map() ), ([id, obj]) => obj );
```

```js
var events = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane','Bella']},
  {id: 3, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 4, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Gary', 'Jane']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Ted', 'Laura']},
  {id: 5, name: 'Football Game', invitees: ['Jim', 'Samantha']},
];

var result = Array.from (
    events.reduce ( (acc, obj) => acc.set(obj.id,
        Object.assign({}, obj, {invitees: [...new Set(
            [...(acc.get(obj.id) || obj).invitees, ...obj.invitees] )]})
    ), new Map() ), ([id, obj]) => obj );
  
console.log(result);
```